# Android studio fails to commit (Unchecks the files when trying to commit)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make the first commit. As you see I checked those "Unversioned files" but when I press "Commit", "Unversioned files" become unchecked. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: did you solve it, Im facing same

Comment: Same problem here... any solution found?

Answer (score 1):

Before commit,

1. In Android Studio, right click on the project directory.
2. Go to Git.
3. Click Add.

It will add your files into VCS.
Now you can select and commit your files :)